# X-axis labels for the reputation graph are collapsed in Edge

Tags: bug, design, reputation-graph, microsoft-edge

X-axis labels for the reputation graph are collapsed in Edge (`Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134`)
[image: Edge chart featuring collapsed x-axis labels]

 rather than spread along the axis, as in Chrome or Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Yet another victim of the CSS rework on the profile page. The inevitable CSS refactor loop: _my god, this CSS is full of weird browser-specific code_ -> _Let's clean it up using modern standards_ -> _Oh no! Browser-specific bugs!_ -> _Add browser-specific workarounds_ -> _my god, this CSS is full of weird browser-specific code_

Comment: I must be blind took me a while to realize what the issue was..

Comment: The time period labels are in a `<ul>` with `justify-content: space-evenly !important`. [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=space-evenly) says "not really".

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SE: [Reputation Graph X Axis Bug in Edge and IE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322159/289905).

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9504/15479