# Reputation graph x-axis labels seem off-by-one on profile activity

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

Some other "off-by-1 day" bug existed on the reputation graph with bars showing daily gains (e.g. : [Off-by-one bug in reputation graph legend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296743/off-by-one-bug-in-reputation-graph-legend)), but this post refers to an "off-by-one *year*" on the total reputation graph :
[image: Profile page, activity tab]

I remember starting to be really active in mid 2017, but the x-axis legend seems to indicate that the increase in reputation started in mid 2018.

Also, a bit more disturbing, it seems to me that we are near the end of 2018, while the labels seem to imply we are near end 2019.

This graph has buggy or at least misleading x-axis labelling to me.

[image: Fixed graph and handmade red circle]

As per some comments, the issue seems the same with the per-month x-axis scale.

Comment: I received a downvote and was about to ask "Why ???", but I deserved it : I didn't provide a screeshot with handmade red circle. Now this is done. Please accept my sincere apologies to the community.

Comment: By the way, I can see in the tags that "reputation graph" refers to the bar graph showing daily gains. What is the name of this one ?

Comment: This was reported on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321356/323179).

Comment: a stupid question: how to make the graph by year?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think my graph is by year because I asked a question many (5+) years ago, while your activity seem to have started in 2017, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd like to show you mine, as the legend displays "APRJULOCTJAN" for the left half of the graph, and nothing to the right.

Comment: Same for months, mine goes from Apr to Jan and implies we're at the end of march.

Comment: X-axis squash issue has been reported multiple times: [ex1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322159/reputation-graph-x-axis-bug-in-edge-and-ie) [ex2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375164/x-axis-labels-for-the-reputation-graph-are-collapsed-in-edge). The other issue was correctly pointed out as a [cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321356/reputation-graph-goes-to-2020) by Laurel and is also very much related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354661/reputation-graph-where-exactly-are-the-year-labels-pointing-to)

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] for me since i am just 1 year user.

Comment: issue with y-axis on the same element : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380127/shouldnt-this-be-6-4k?cb=1

Answer (score 4):

After having a thought about this after the y-axis "bug" that I posted, I noticed actually, these labels are confusing, like this:

[image: real rep]

And also, the number actually corresponds with right after the number not at the number as you might have expected. (No offense if I used your freehand circle image...), but first, you might say "there's a bug with this image" and then you think about what's actually going on. So if this is not a bug, then this has to be the case.

Comment: I think the vertical bars you drawn should be even further right. I posted the question on the very beginning of 2019, so the graph ends with 2019. At that point, I'd say the labels are really not close enough to these bars. If these bars were at least slightly visible, that would really help for sure !

Comment: I don't think this logic applies to the graph in my question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392601/reputation-graph-year-label-misleading

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s That is another type of bug.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a similar bug in the rep graph but I didn't think it warranted a Meta 'probe' in itself. However, now that I've come across this Q/A thread, here it is (note that I can't post images as comments):

[image]

Note the total misalignment of the time-axis labels. (Maybe this only happens for folks with < 1 year on their card?)

Comment: This has already been reported: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375164/x-axis-labels-for-the-reputation-graph-are-collapsed-in-edge (as mentioned in [the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378872/reputation-graph-x-axis-labels-seem-off-by-one-on-profile-activity/391019#comment662202_378872))

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing OK! I missed that. However, this image makes it a lot clearer.