# Shouldn't this be 6.4k?

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

I just saw a person's reputation graph and there were two `6.5k`s in the graph. The circled one *should* actually be `6.4k`.

[image: Why are there two 6.5k?!]

Is that a bug or something else?

Comment: The "bottom" one? What does that mean? The first chronologically?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I mean there is 2 `6.5k`s and I mean the bottom one is the first one.

Comment: It’s probably three equidistant values, all rounded to the nearest 100. For example, if you have 6450, 6500, 6550, they have the same distances between eachother, but are rounded as 6.5k, 6.5k, 6.6k. I don’t think this is a bug.

Comment: @Xufox it's still a bug in the sense that the result does not convey useful and intelligible meaning, rounding shenanigans or not.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier one could argue that any of the possible workaround will come with their own drawbacks here: allow more precision here and you'll lose precision on the x axis, change the Y axis ranges and you'll loose precision there. The information is still somehow meaningful: from a glance you can see that top is 6.6 and bottom 6.5, if you want more precise data, there is a tooltip when hovering.

Comment: I agree, if we are to use the min and max value of the line to calculate the axis ticks of a lower precision we should not use rounding but rather flooring. That's pretty standard practice if I recall correctly from my uni days.

Comment: @apokryfos it could very well still be flooring, [6550-6625] would produce these if floored.

Comment: @Kaiido the problem here is that 3 ticks are being forced. The specific range you mention (which can't really the range in the plot here) can't be drawn with 3 ticks and with 1 decimal place of accuracy, however, it seems that all rep charts have 3 ticks no matter what the figures and the rule for decimal places depends on the number being shown and not the size of the range being used. I'm not saying it's an easy problem but it's a problem that has solutions in various charting software.

Comment: @DavyM that's only true for small values of 5!

Comment: Well it maybe the circled 6.5k actually means 6.45k or 6,450. It's just rounded to the nearest tenth.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @FélixGagnon-Grenier because if you would look at the top and middle values on the Y axis only (kind of hard now with the red circle :P ) you would get the wrong idea with regards to scale. Not that I think rep graphs themselves are all that important to me, but a UI bug it is.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes And if you had 6.4 while it's not 6.4 then you'd have false information, which is worse than anything, but if they did move the range's min to 6.4 or the max to 6.7 you'd have a flatter line, and you would get a wrong idea as to what this graph truly represents: Reputation Change. The one thing that could be done to improve this graph could be to add a tooltip on the Y axis labels with the full value (just like it is when you hover the plot).

Comment: cool, a display bug on the y-axis that goes nicely with the [display bug on the x-axis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378872/reputation-graph-x-axis-labels-seem-off-by-one-on-profile-activity)

Comment: Easy fix: do the rounding however you like. Then check if you ended up with the same value twice. If that's the case adjust the rounding policy to ensure it always displays 3 different values. Sure it's not "pure"  but I prefer having a 6.4, 6.5, 6.6 even if the 6.4 is actually a little closer to 6.5...

Comment: Yeah, seems like a rounding issue. SE has a bunch of those with dates too

Comment: Why don't just write 6400 (or 6450, etc.) instead of 6.4k? To improve readability, you can use thousand separator, e.g. 6 450

Comment: @trolley813 Because then you have to deal with different thousands separators, e.g. 6,450. Mind you there is already that problem with the decimal point (e.g. 6,5k)

Comment: @Xufox It may be "correct" as in expected behaviour given the current implementation, but it's obviously not desired - the graph cannot be interpreted properly by the user. That's a bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you can use space as a universal thousand separator, since it obviously cannot be misread as a decimal point (unlike comma and point).

Comment: It seems like the answer is for the graph writing code to not include a third value when it duplicates one of the extreme values.  The middle value there does not help the user read and understand the graph better.  I don't see a reason the have a middle value at all on a small graph like that.

Comment: Related network-wide request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/help-us-improve-the-user-profile-and-settings/319449#319449

Comment: @Elin Just eliding the middle value doesn't solve the problem (it arguably makes the problem worse) because then you have two labels that appear to unambiguously reflect the 6.5k and 6.6k mark but (as described above) apparently do no such thing!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They should use reasonable max and min values and then that's it, especially with the shading there is no reason at all to have a middle number, especially when it is not a number like what is on a normal axis.

Comment: While this is a good question, if the title said "Shouldn't this axis label be 6.4k?", I wouldn't click it.

Comment: Not only the labels are bad, the grey horizontal bars are bad too. One should label only the points that match the numbers shown. Don’t draw ticks and round the labels. Instead, find rounded labels, then put the ticks where those exact values are reached. If that leads to too few ticks (0 or 1), there needs to be a special case. But usually this won’t be a problem. Good graphing is not hard if you think about the problem a bit.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I agree about the horizontal bars, only esthetics and misleadings, but about changing the Y axis range, no. The real goal of these graphs is to let us know from a glance if we can trust this user's contributions or not, by showing the community's reception across time. The important part is the shape of the plot, not the actual data (for this, you have the big bold span at the left side). For instance, if the values were [5,950 - 6,050] changing the Y axis range to include the real 6.4k would make it look like [a flat line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLxPD.png), while it's not.

Comment: @CrisLuengo And while looking at a single case to make a good graph of it may look easy, good graphing is an human task. Programmatically generating good graphs for every cases with dynamic data is near impossible. You need to understand what is important in the data you are exposing to know how it should be shown the best way. The important part of dynamic data is... well dynamic.

Comment: @Kaiido: I didn’t suggest always including 3 rounded values on the y-axis. You only need 2 values to understand the scale of the changes, and if only 1 or no rounded values are within the min and max, a special case is needed. This could look like showing the (rounded) reputation + the total reputation change. Rounding numbers attached to tick marks is misleading, and should *never* be done,  or even in relatively minor plots like these. — Regardibg your second comment: the meaning of the data is always the same here.

Comment: @CrisLuengo *"find rounded labels"* I didn't made it. Even if there is only two, you'll have the same issue. For users with hundreds K rep the roundings are bigger, but the change may not be. Now, I agree, not rounding might actually be the best move, while I also understand the ones from the design who told "What? 70px just for Jon's tick's label?" when they decided to go with the "1m" format.

Answer (score -20, accepted):

Just to clarify regarding some *misconception* here:

**No, in this period, this shouldn't be 6.4k.**

The graphic always has two extremal values (the max and the min for a given period of time), and the middle value is simply being the average of the two.

If on a given period the lower bound was 667 and the upper bound was 777, then the three displayed values would be 667 | 722 | 777.

If on a given period the lower bound was 6500 and the upper bound was 6505, then the three displayed values would be 6.5k | 6.5k | 6.5k.

The misconception was that you may have believed that it was a scale with marks every 100 points, which it is not.

As of how to prevent equal values from being displayed, that could require to adapt the represented period to be a longer one in some circumstances. Or add more significant digits. Or set the graduation to be of at least 200 points between the min and the max.

Comment: It's not a misconception, it is the standard reading of axes on an XY plot.

Comment: If it's a misconception it's only because the axis labels are wrong (don't show sufficient precision)

Comment: Well if it's actually a scale with marks every 50 points can we increase the decimal presicion to the hundreds place?

Comment: @zixuan No we can't increase the precision. The range of possibe values is [1 - 1,086,244+] while the range of minimal change is [0 - 2] (single vals seems to be shown on a single tick) If we had room for a 6 digit precision number, a lot more bug reports would have raised because of the unused space.

Comment: @AndrewMorton An easy way to prevent equal values from being displayed is to just start the scale (and the graph) at 0... but that would make too much sense.

Comment: So basically "It's not a bug, it's just a new sample for the next edition of 'How to Lie with Statistics'"?

Comment: I downvoted you answer because even though you explained how the existing system worked, I disagree with the way it does, and find it confusing

Comment: @Ferrybig: Why would you downvote an answer for accurately explaining how a system works... because you don't like how the system works? I mean sure, fine, you may not like it. But calling the answer "not useful" because you don't like the information it contains is kind of silly, isn't it?

Comment: @NicolBolas plenty of times, people understand how stuff works, but are deeply disgusted that they work like that (cue politics) and express that via votes. Also, it's a freaking internet post without any repercussion in the real world (like answers on main).

Answer (score 9):

> Is that a bug or something else?

The shown labels on the y-axis are three [equidistant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385598/what-y-axis-transformation-is-used-on-the-reputation-chart), rounded values. As such they are likely not a bug in the logic of the plot, but they could be made much more helpful.

Problem is that the rounding is not adapted to the shown range. The shown range of the y-axis is approx. 100-200 rep points, while the rounding is to multiples of 100 rep points. That's bad because it makes the shown values rather useless. The rounded tick values should leave at least one digit more visible to be useful as already suggested in [Cœur's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380202/1536976).