# What is the purpose of images?

Tags: discussion, meta

So far when looking through Meta Stack Overflow, I've noticed one thing that's kind of confused me

> Don't post code or errors as pictures!

I get the reasons behind it. It decreases searchability, makes it harder to read, not everyone can access them, etc., but I'm here today to ask (what I assume is) the harder question, so why does the image option exist? For some sites, like Stack Exchange site *[Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tour)*, the image is crucial for part identification.

But on Stack Overflow it seems useless, and it is just something for people, who are new to the site, get called out on. And if you can answer that, then I ask you this; what's the point of pictures on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Images of `text` is really frowned upon; code, errors, data for example. That doesn't mean images are bad, just images of things that shouldn't be images.

Comment: You've switched between Stack Overflow to Stack Exchange midway through your question, but your question is posted on Meta Stack Overflow. Is your question, "What's the point of images on Meta Stack Overflow?", "What's the point of images on Meta Stack Exchange?", "What's the point of images on any site in the Stack Exchange?", or "What's the point of images on Stack Overflow?"?

Comment: It's only most of the time that people posting images are wrong. If there isn't a warning that comes up saying "STOP: If you're about to post an image of some text, don't!" when someone tries to add an image to their question, then there should be.

Comment: One word: diagrams.

Comment: ``But on stack exchange it seems useless`` I think you mean Stack Overflow.

Comment: @zixuan yes sorry fixed the post didn't get much sleep last night  the questions are "whats the point of images on stack overflow" and "whats the point of images on stack overflow meta" sorry for the confusion (I'm sorry........ :( )

Comment: Sometimes a picture really is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Note that there are also [visual programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) where the code is literally an image.

Comment: @BSMP joke programming languages neverless

Comment: Questions about them are on topic.

Comment: yes, but how many of those questions exist?

Comment: "what's the point of pictures on stack overflow meta?" Without the ability to add images to meta posts no one would be able to provide Red Freehand Circles, rendering many posts completely unintelligible.

Comment: Also, posting images is handy when the question is about image processing, so you can literally show the input & output. Eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234924/4014959 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269363/4014959

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With regards to the main site, images can make the presentation of the problem (or solution) clearer, *in addition to text*. For example, in an answer, you could say:

"In the Options interface, click on the Preferences tab and scroll down to the Tab Size option and input the number of spaces you want."

Or you could say that *and post a picture*, which could be helpful if the interface is complicated. Posting a picture will help get the idea across more easily, though the post should stand on its own without the picture.

Images could also help when describing a visual issue in an IDE (for example, about what the console is displaying, or about how intellisense is working or not working). They could also help when asking questions about CSS issues or graphs, to help get the idea across more clearly than *only* plain text would.

Answer (score 6):

> But on stack exchange it seems useless, just something for people who are new to the site get called out on.

On Stack Overflow, that's only if you post code or sometimes error messages as pictures. The disadvantage of that is that answerers can't copy the code and try to run that to see what the error is.

Otherwise, images can actually be useful. For example, say you are trying to run an IDE and when you click a certain thing, the IDE crashes.

In that case, you can make an image pointing to where that thing you clicked is so people can understand it more clearly.

> And if you can answer that, then I ask you this; what's the point of pictures on stack exchange meta?

Also fairly easy to spot.

If there is a miscoloring in the SO interface, you can post an image to show where the miscoloring is.

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380127/shouldnt-this-be-6-4k) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

There are many situations dealing with gui based technologies where the only way to provide a MCVE is to screenshot the application. One in particular that comes to mind is Unity (game engine).

Another situation where this occurs is in graphical bugs. While the code that produces the bug is still a needed part of the question, the result can also be helpful and sometimes necessary in tracking down the problem.

That is true on the main site and extends to meta, when talking about those questions.