# Reputation graph has wrong dates

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

My graph should show the rise from the beginning of the 2020 or so.

[image]

Comment: Your posts from 2020 start in June. So, *at best* you'd have started getting rep from the middle of 2020. I don't know when exactly uoi started getting a lot of votes - the graph suggests around New Year. It's possible that's when your posts got the most votes. If you had around 10 votes between June and December(-ish) it would hardly be visible on the graph.

Comment: Actually, investigating further - [the reputation page on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640180/paxmees?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=2) suggests that you should have a visible increase. In [the section between 6th of July 2020 to 18th of August 2020](https://i.imgur.com/mHzN9QT.png) you got 321 reputation. That's more than 30% of the graph. That should definitely be noticeable. [The graph page of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640180/paxmees?tab=reputation&sort=graph) (scroll down) [does show the rep gain](https://i.imgur.com/bY7OtgW.png)

Comment: OK, looking at it now - it seems the marker for the years is misleading. The place where it says "2021" in your screenshot seems to actually correspond to the middle of 2020. It's possible this is a bug based on time. We're at the beginning of 2021, so there is no not space on the X-axis for it. It could be that the label pushes everything out. If so, in, say, six months time the graph would cover more of 2021, so there would be enough space for the label. This would explain the output. It's still misleading, though.

Comment: This should have a warning: "This graph not to scale." :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey or maybe just mark what the label refers to: https://i.imgur.com/2skMTCv.png (I guessed the positions)

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378872/reputation-graph-x-axis-labels-seem-off-by-one-on-profile-activity